# Android Studio Device Monitor shows nothing

Tags: android-studio, android-device-monitor

I have an app which is working fine, but whenever I go to Android Device Monitor, there is nothing in both devices and DDMS [image]

What should I do so that my project is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This worked with the first device created and not with a second device : DDMS showing empty file explorer for online emulator. I deleted all devices and recreated a new one and it works. I think that only a single device can be run with debugging

Answer (score -2):

You need to run your Application first and then run the Android device monitor, it should populate the tabs after that.